# Count the number of rows with equal values in two specified columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, google-spreadsheets

I have two columns in MS Excel/LibreOffice Calc/Google Spreadsheets with numbers. I would like to count the number of rows which have identical values in both columns.

In the following example:

```
Column A | Column B
   1     |     4
   2     |     2
   3     |     5
   3     |     3
   5     |     3
```

there are two rows with equal numbers: rows 2 (2=2) and 4 (3=3). I was hoping for solutions like `=SUM(A1:A5=B1:B5)` to work; unfortunately, they don't.

**UPDATE**

I know the solution would easy if I were to create a third column in which I would compare each pair of values, row by row (as Dave and Joe suggested, using e.g. `=IF(A1=B1, 1, 0)`); however, I'm looking for a one-liner as I don't want to clutter the spreadsheet with intermediate results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're nearly right. You can adapt your formula slightly like this:

```
{=SUM(IF(A1:A5=B1:B5,1,0))}
```

Type this in without the curly `{}` brackets, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> so that Excel knows it's an array formula. The curly brackets represent the fact it's an array formula.

Answer (score 3):

In Excel you can use `SUMPRODUCT` function in a similar way to Andi's solution, but avoiding "array entry":

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(A1:A5=B1:B5))`

that will also count any blank rows (as does Andi's) so if you want to avoid that change to this version:

`=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5<>"")*(A1:A5=B1:B5))`

Answer (score 1):

I would make it simpler with an IF Else statement so it could apply to numbers and characters

In C1, add the following

```
=IF(A1=B1, 1, 0)
```

Then, drag the formula down the length of the table and underneath, SUM the entire Cell

```
 =SUM(C1:C10)   // enter correct row numbers!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use another column to store partial result, you can follow this way:

```
Column A | Column B | Column C (equal condition)
  1      |   4      | =IF(A1=B1;1;0)
  2      |   2      | =IF(A2=B2;1;0)
  3      |   5      | =IF(A3=B3;1;0)
  3      |   3      | =IF(A4=B4;1;0)
  5      |   3      | =IF(A5=B5;1;0)
```

In the cell C6 you write this formula `=SUM(C1:C5)`